# Can tomcat docbase have wildcards?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, server.xml

Is it possible to use wildcards in the docbase as in example below?

```
<Context path="/somepath" docBase="name-somewildcards"/>
```

UPDATE

The name of the war file is usually name-vers-date and I want to use some regex in the docbase so that the path is always the same if the ver or date change